# Merging two folders using git

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I'm working on a project with some people who have never used git before. Not knowing the capabilities of git, they created two version of the project: development and production. These two versions are both present in the current environment.

To complicate things further, this other user created these folders in addition to the old development folder. So the project directory looks like this

```
/root
  /.git
  /proj         (old dev folder with my own code in it)
  /dev_proj     (new folder which I would like to merge /prod with)
  /prod_proj       (production code)
```

So what I'd like to do is merge the work that I've done in `/proj` with the work in the `/dev_proj`. Is there a way to do this with git?

I've thought about creating a branch, copying all the files from `/proj` to `/dev_proj` and merging that branch with master. Would this work?

Thanks and if I could clarify something let me know.

Comment: Are proj and dev_proj separate folders in the same git repo or separate branches, or separate git repositories?  Are there any changes in dev_proj that aren't in your project files?  If so, do you have the way the code was before either set of changes?

Comment: proj, dev_proj, and prod_proj are folders with the git project. This is the structure in the current master repository. The other programmer updated all of his code in the /dev_proj folder. So my updates are in /proj while his are in /_proj.

I think he did a single commit to commit all of updated files into /dev_proj so there isn't really a history for those changes.

Comment: But proj has your history?  Do you know which changeset he pulled from to develop his code?

Comment: How did he create dev_proj?  Did he just copy the files and then do git add?

Also, are you sharing a git server and using push or do you have a distributed system?

Comment: I've updated the directory structure to show where the git repo is. He pulled in a change set that only had /proj and .git in the root directory. So he copied /proj to /dev_proj and /prod_proj. Then he made his respective changes to each copy of the code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a git expert, but I would suggest making a new branch, rooted at the change where he copied his code from before making the changes.

```
git branch devProjTemp <commit-id>
```

(Don't forget to `git checkout devProjTemp`.)  Then copy all the files from dev_proj to proj, and commit.  Then you should be able to merge from the new branch to master and it should do the right thing.

If you want to have separate dev and prod data, I would also suggest creating a branch for one of them.  Specifically, I would create a prod branch and copy the changes from prod_proj over to that.

Then, I would delete prod_proj and dev_proj in the master branch and the prod branch.

Does your coworker not know about branches?  I would do some teaching there.  It shouldn't be so hard once you've created the branches.

Comment: I'm not a git expert, but this is the only way I've found to solve this kind of problem.