# Git - Merging a non-git folder with a similar folder under git

Tags: git, merge, webserver

I can't seem to find anything to help my situation & was hoping someone could help me as I'm not entirely fluent with git yet but am loving it.

We have a dev server under git control displaying our dev branch. We then have a master branch in addition to to the dev branch which has a stable version of the website.

Then, on our production server we have our stable site but due to how things played out, it is not under git version control, we have just manually updated the files we needed. Obviously the stable master branch files look somewhat similar to the manually managed production set of files.

We'd like to eventually get the production server under git control, displaying the master branch, just like the dev server reflects the dev branch.

However, I'm not sure how to go about setting up the git repo on the production server and somehow merging it with the master branch. Could anyone please provide some pointers, hints or direction?

The only thing I found online involved something along the lines of setting up another two repos (for a total of 3), one being a parent of the other two and somehow bringing them all together that way. I was hoping for a different solution (or at least a "ya, that's correct" so I don't go down some stupid rabbit hole. ( not sure if this [Merging two folders using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695619/merging-two-folders-using-git) might be some sort of start?? but the lack of responses made it hard to see if that was the right thing to pursue )

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you correctly the site on your production server is based on your master branch (or some other commit in your git repo) but not exactly the same, i.e. with some manual changes in it and you don't want to lose this manual changes. Here is what I do in cases like this:

1. Check out or clone your master branch (or the commit your production servers data is based on) somewhere.
2. You now have a clean working copy with the production servers "base".
3. Copy all data from your production server to this clean working copy.
4. Use `git diff` to examine all changes and commit the relevant ones.
5. If the base you checked out in step 1 is not your master, you can now simply merge the manual changes using `git merge master` with your master.

I hope I understood you correctly and this guides you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks siegi! On first glance I was thinking you were off a little but actually I think this is just it! Unfortunately the production files are going to be a huge hodge podge of files that aren't exactly from any particular commit and are mostly manual (but I'm sure they're similar to something in my history.. So I think I will do something just like that and cross my fingers that the git diff isn't too ridiculous!

Thanks for the prompt response ;-) I'll post back with how it goes. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to version the production server: it should already be versioned!

What you need to do is having **one single** repo, that will be deployed everywhere: production server, staging server, local dev machines, etc.

You'll work locally however you want, but in the production server, you'll simply stay on the *master* branch.
Locally, when you finish working on something, and it is fully working, tested, etc. Simply rebase (or merge) it into (with) *master*, and `git push origin master` it. Then, on your production server `git fetch && git rebase origin/master` (or pull) to get the changes.

Comment: thanks for clearing up any doubt, those are sometimes the lifesavers! we do in fact have just a single repo and I think I just used the wrong terminology. :-/ what you described is pretty much our configuration, I just need to convert the manually updated files on the production server to be under git control and set it as the master branch ;-) thanks Samy

Comment: What kind of modified files? If you mean uploaded files, you shouldn't version them. If it's config files, you can use environment variables to set configuration information ; or version *template* config files (suffixed by -dist for example) only, and ignore the original ones, then you create a config file from the versioned one in your production server. I recommend you taking a look at 12factor.net that talks about deployment good practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably *push* to a repository with a working directory. You will get errors about non-bare repositories, and fighting the system will be bad for your ulcer.

What you ought to do is:

1. rsync/scp your production files onto a local system, and merge them with the appropriate branch (e.g. master).
2. Push your master branch to a repository that will be visible to your production host.
3. Run `git clone` from your production machine.
4. Since you are no longer making changes on your production host, you might even set up `git pull` as a cron job.

As long as you don't make manual changes in the Git working tree on your production machine, you won't have to do anything other than `git pull` when you want to roll out the latest changes. Just remember: pull from your production system, don't push to it.

Comment: Roger that, thanks. We are set up this way on the development server using the post-update hook. The annoying thing will be when the server wants to modify files (like wordpress updates or whatever) but I believe there is another hook to handle that somewhat smoothly that I read about on [this web focused git workflow blogpost](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/)